# how to run one function alone in parallel that depend on another big function

Tags: python-3.x, python-multiprocessing

I have a requirement like below

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
import pandas as pd
import time
def test():
    print("Parent")
def opt_by_region(a,b,c,d):
    print("inside process")
    time.sleep(1)
    return b
def opt():
    pool=Pool(processes=4)
    df=pd.DataFrame([1,2])
    res=[pool.apply_async(fun,args=(r,df,3,4))for r in range(5)]
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
```

This is sample structure of my code that am working.Here I need to run "opt_by_region" only in parallel for each region. but region and other variable are getting from function "opt"(it is not running in parallel)
so how can I solve this.how can I put wait "opt_by_region" to trigger with all the variables from function "opt".could anyone please suggest ideas it would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, try removing that list comprehension from around pool.apply_async. You want to supply a list of your arguments to apply_async, even if the list elements are containers or objects.

Next, I think you have a typo, and should be supplying the function you want to iterate (fun <-> opt_by_region)

```
args = [(r,df,3,4) for r in range(5)]
res = pool.apply_async(opt_by_region,args=args)
```

Comment: if I am using pyspark to implement this program(currently used pandas) will it be replacing the multiprocessing?whether spark its self take care the parallelism?